# Yii Alias or Params

Tags: php, yii2

Which one is better to set directory folder for global usage?

Below are set to `yii2` web config.

```
'aliases' => [
    '@uploads' => 'uploads/csv',
],
```

Or in

```
'params' => [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'uploadCsv' => 'uploads/csv/',
];
```

Comment: The alias are expressed  create for manage properly path .. so the first  should be the better ..

Answer (score 0):

If I am using the **Yii Advanced template** I prefer using the alias option.For the **Yii basic template** any will be fine.

Example: in the *common/config/bootstrap.php* of Advanced template

```
Yii::setAlias('@uploads', dirname(__DIR__) . '/uploads/csv');
```